# filling running total over all month although its null

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables. One only with all periods. Second with Account, Amount and period.

I want to build a View that lists Amount kumulated, period and account. Also if I don't have an fact for a period in my table should be appear the period in my view with the last amount.

```
select distinct 
    account, b.periode, 
    SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY b.periode RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
from 
    fakten a
full join 
    perioden b on a.periode = b.periode
order by b.periode
```

it like this:

```
1       1   6
2       1   4
1       2   13
2       2   3
NULL    3   NULL
1       4   46
2       5   48
NULL    6   NULL
NULL    7   NULL
1       8   147
NULL    9   NULL
NULL    10  NULL
NULL    11  NULL
NULL    12  NULL
```

I need it like:

```
1       1   6
2       1   4
1       2   13
2       2   3
1       3   13
2       3   3
1       4   46
2       4   3
1       5   46
2       5   48
1       6   46
2       6   46
and so one...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some more details to be able to actually help here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: perhaps some details on how:  NULL    3   NULL   turns into: 1       3   13   in the question would be helpful for people to answer

Comment: only up to period 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`full join` is not the right approach.  Instead, generate the rows you want using a `cross join`.  Then use `left join` and `group by` to do the calculation.

```
select a.account, p.periode, 
       SUM(f.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.account ORDER BY p.periode) 
from (select distinct account from fakten) a cross join -- you probably have an account table, use it
     perioden p
     on a.periode = p.periode left join
     fakten f
     on f.account = a.account and f.periode = p.periode
group by a.account, p.periode
order by a.account, p.periode;
```